# Сдвиг циклической матрицы на k элементов

Tags: python, матрицы

Нужно выполнить сдвиг квадратной матрицы на k элементов таким образом: Элементы первой строки сдвигаются в последний столбец сверху вниз, из него - в последнюю строку справа налево, из нее - в первый столбец снизу вверх, из него в первую строку; для остальных элементов - аналогично.

Я так понимаю змейкой должно сдвигаться на K элемент матрицы, но как это сделать в python не понимаю.Это мой код - строки переходят в столбцы. Но оказывается по-другому нужно сделать по заданию(

```
from random import randint
n=int(input("Введите размерность квадратной матрицы = "))


def printMatrix ( mas ): 
   for i in range ( len(mas) ): 
      for j in range ( len(mas[i]) ): 
          print ( "{:4d}".format(mas[i][j]), end = "" ) 
      print ()

if(n>0):
    mas= [[randint(1, 10) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    print("Создан массив")
    printMatrix(mas)
#k = int(input("Введите сдвиг на k элементов"))


def printMatrix2 ( mas2 ): 
   print("Вывод сдвинутой матрицы")
   for i in range ( len(mas2) ): 
      for j in range ( len(mas2[i]) ): 
          print ( "{:4d}".format(mas2[i][j]), end = "" ) 
      print ()

mas2 = [[_ for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
def sdvig(mas):
        for i in range(n):
             for j in range(n):
                mas2[n-i-1][n-j-1]=mas[j][n-i-1]
sdvig(mas)
printMatrix2(mas2)
```

Вот так работает мой код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также на просторах интернета нашел эту задачу только на c#, тут в for работают, а в питоне он реализован по-другому, пробовал так тоже, не работает, из-за неопытности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется, или это обычный поворот матрицы на 90 градусов? если да, то причем тут сдвиги?

Comment: Ну то что я написал в коде - да, 90 градусов, но мне нужен сдвиг. Неправильно сделал задание, просто реализовал именно вот эти строчки "Элементы первой строки сдвигаются в последний столбец сверху вниз, из него - в последнюю строку справа налево, из нее - в первый столбец снизу вверх, из него в первую строку; для остальных элементов - аналогично."

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rotate-matrix-in-python ?

Comment: да я понял, что я сделал, меня вот интересует именно сдвиг на k элементов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой алгоритм у меня получился, можно будет его потом улучшить или оптимизировать

```
def gen_matrix(n):
    k = 1
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        temp = []
        for j in range(n):
            temp.append(k)
            k+=1
        res.append(temp)
    return res


def shift(matrix, k):
    res = []
    N = len(matrix)
    P = (N+N-2)*2
    k = k % P

    # сохраняем периметр матрицы в res
    for vector in matrix[0]:
        res.append(vector)
    for vector in matrix[1:-1]:
        res.append(vector[-1])
    for vector in reversed(matrix[-1]):
        res.append(vector)
    for vector in reversed(matrix[1:-1]):
        res.append(vector[0])

    shift_res = res[-k:] + res[:-k] # сдвигаем циклически массив

    # перезаписываем периметр матрицы
    for i in range(N):
        matrix[0][i] = shift_res.pop(0)
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        matrix[i][0] = shift_res.pop(-1)
        matrix[i][-1] = shift_res.pop(0)
    for i in range(N):
        matrix[-1][i] = shift_res.pop(-1)

    return matrix

m3 = gen_matrix(3)
m4 = gen_matrix(4)
m5 = gen_matrix(5)

print(*m4, sep='\n\r')
print(*shift(m4, 3), sep='\n\r')
```

Для быстрой проверки дописал генератор квадратной матрицы

Вот что получается для k=3:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы очень круты, Роман! Спасибо вам огромное, без вас я бы не справился, сейчас хотя бы понятен алгоритм с индексами в матрице